# PyYAML throwing unsolvable error

Tags: yaml, python-3.4, pyyaml

I am working with YAML files and I am stuck in using the "|" for literal quotes.

I am using PyYAML.

Major issue here is that it works for the first level "Dictionary" Key in the below code but for the second level "notes" key it did not work.

I have tried using ">" "|+" "|-" but nothing worked.

```
Description: |

    This is a sample text showing that it works fine here.

Signatures:
    -   {   
            returnValue:        'placeholder',
            notes: |

                Its not working here
    }
    -   {   
            returnValue:        'another placeholder',
            notes: ' 
                     This is working here 

                    '
        }
```

I checked the syntax on http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ , https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/ and others as well, I got the error that

**ERROR:
while scanning for the next token
found character '|' that cannot start any token
  in "", line 8, column 24:
                    notes: |**

I went through the thread [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines) and few others, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, always make the minimal example that throws the error:

```
{      notes: |

                Its not working here
}
```

If you look at the [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and search for the string "literal style" your first hit is in the Table of Cotents, section 8.1.2 which is part of the description of **Block styles**

Your code specifies flow style for the mapping with its use of `{ }`, within that you cannot have block style literal scalars.

You should just make the whole YAML consistently block style (remove the `{}` and the `,` between mapping elements):

```
Description: |

    This is a sample text showing that it works fine here.

Signatures:
    -   returnValue: placeholder
        notes: |

            Its not working here
    -   returnValue:  another placeholder
        notes: '
                This is working here

                '
```

BTW, because default chomping on literal scalars is [clipping](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794682), it doesn't change anything if you add extra empty lines at the end of such scalars.

(PyYAML only supports YAML 1.1, but wrt this the specification has not changed).